# PHP code inside WP molecule

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a PHP snippet inside a molecule in WP. WP Editor allows to insert `<code> </code>`
but even if I wrap PHP with that it does not seem to help.

All I want it to insert the current year, so I'm OK with either PHP or JS or whatever else WP supports.

Anyone had experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two plugins that come to mind. One is **wp-syntax** http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/, a rich code display plugin with many features.  You'll have to switch to code editing view to insert your `<code>` or `<pre>` tag with the PHP snippet.

The other one is a low tech homebrew of mine, "**include custom field**": http://pp19dd.com/wordpress-plugin-include-custom-field/

The homebrew is a shortcode plugin that lets you place arbitrary code or data inside a custom field, and then inject it into the post with something like [include mycode1].  Note that it'll be up to you to encode it to where it can be shown, or modify it to where it acts like a code highlighter (can be done easily with highlight_string.)

Reason I like my brew version is because it a) separates a blog post from the code, and b) survives numerous editing cycles and/or imports.  All  other inline solutions annoy me to no end.

Comment: Hey, that's cool. I was just about to go do into the code and hard-code it in ;)